# PHP Curl does not work with a proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Have the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$pageContents = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have tried all combinations of CURLOPT, somehow NONE of the proxies seem to work. If I comment out the line with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy) it  works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What format is your `$proxy` variable? The code itself looks ok to me.

Comment: I have not exploded the $proxy ... ip:port

Comment: That all sounds correct. If the proxy isn't on port 80 then maybe a networking issue?

Comment: could you elaborate please. As I said...none of the proxies work. I am missing something.

Answer (score -1):

Use following code.

```
$url = 'URL';
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_page;
```

To disable the proxy simply set it to null.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, null);
```

Comment: Set proxy as $proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';

Comment: True...but I have a different set of proxies.